# Difference between g++ and clang++ with enable_if

Tags: c++, clang++, enable-if

I want to write a function that returns an instance of a type T but behaves differently depending on how T can be constructed. Say I have structs like these

```
#include <type_traits>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
#include <iostream>

struct A {}; 
struct B {}; 
struct C { 
  C(A a) {
    std::cout << "C" << std::endl;
  }
};
```

I want to create Cs by giving them an A. I have a struct like so that uses enable_if to choose one of two functions:

```
struct E {

  template< bool condition = std::is_constructible<C, A>::value,std::enable_if_t<condition,int> = 0>
  C get() {
    return C{A{}};
  }
  template< bool condition = std::is_constructible<C, B>::value,std::enable_if_t<condition,bool> = false>
  C get() {
    return C{B{}};
  }
};
```

This compiles fine with g++82 (and I think also g++9), but clang9 gives me the error

```
$ clang++ --std=c++17 main.cpp 
main.cpp:26:12: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'C'
    return C{B{}};
           ^~~~~~
main.cpp:6:8: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'B' to 'const C' for 1st argument
struct C {
       ^
main.cpp:6:8: note: candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'B' to 'C' for 1st argument
struct C {
       ^
main.cpp:7:3: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'B' to 'A' for 1st argument
  C(A a) {
  ^
1 error generated.
```

even though the enable_if should hide that function. (I call `E e; auto c = e.get();`). If I don't hardcode C but instead use a template to pass in C it works in both compilers.

```
template<typename T>
struct F {

  template< bool condition = std::is_constructible<T, A>::value,std::enable_if_t<condition,int> = 0>
  T get() {
    return T{A{}};
  }
  template< bool condition = std::is_constructible<T, B>::value,std::enable_if_t<condition,bool> = false>
  T get() {
    return T{B{}};
  }
};
```

I don't understand why clang apparently typechecks the body of the function even though the function should be disabled by enable_if.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both compiler are right,

http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res#8.1

> The validity of a template may be checked prior to any instantiation. [ Note: Knowing which names are type names allows the syntax of every template to be checked in this way. — end note ] The program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if:
>
> (8.1)
>   - no valid specialization can be generated for a template or a substatement of a constexpr if statement within a template and the template is not instantiated, or
>
> [..]
>
> (8.4)
>   - a hypothetical instantiation of a template immediately following its definition would be ill-formed due to a construct that does not depend on a template parameter, or

`return C{B{}};` is not template dependent, and wrong. clang is fine by diagnosing the issue.

Comment: Paragraph 8.4 also applies.

Answer (score 2):

Since you seem to have access to compilers supporting c++17 you could use `if constexpr` instead of `enable_if` to accomplish what you want.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct A {};

struct B {};

struct C {
    explicit C(A a) {
        std::cout << "C" << std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct False : std::false_type {};

struct E {
    template<typename T = void>
    C get() const {
        if constexpr (std::is_constructible_v<C, A>) {
            return C{A{}};
        } else if constexpr (std::is_constructible_v<C, B>) {
            return C{B{}};
        } else {
            static_assert(False<T>::value, "Error");
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    const auto C{E{}.get()};
    return 0;
}
```